# display results in my view in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

controller function  :

```
function my_feeds()
{   
    $this->load->model('membership_model');
    $query = $this->membership_model->get_my_feeds();
    if($query->num_rows()>0) {
        $this->load->view('my_feed');
    }
```

view:

```
foreach ($query as $row){
    echo $row->title."<br/>";

    }
```

I want to display each title but it does not work. Error: undefined variable query.
What i should do to user $query in my view??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your controller code as below:

You didn't pass data to view file.

```
if($query->num_rows()>0) {
        $res = $query->result();
        $this->load->view('my_feed',array("query"=>$res));
    }
```

Comment: thanks. I have a problem with an xml file , i post a question on stack, can you look over it?

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
function my_feeds()
    {   
        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $query = $this->membership_model->get_my_feeds();
        if($query->num_rows()>0) {
            $this->data['feed'] = $query;
            $this->load->view('my_feed');
        }
```

View:

```
<?php foreach($feed as $value) : ?>
   <td> <?=$value->nameofcolumn;?> </td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```